# Laravel API call through AJAX returns a lot of junk

Tags: json, ajax, laravel

My JS code (button handler):

```
$("#get-password").on("click", () => {
    $.get("https://psycho.bulash.ru/api/get.password").done(
        (data) => {
            console.log(data);
        }
    );
});
```

Laravel route (in routes/api.php):

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function () {
    Route::get('/get.password', 'HelperController@generatePassword');
});
```

Controller method is:

```
public function generatePassword(int $length = 8): string
{
    return response()->json([
        'password' => Str::random($length)
    ], 200);
}
```

JS code put in console the following:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Content-Type:  application/json
Date:          Thu, 18 Mar 2021 08:23:20 GMT

{"password":"50Guz008"}<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' property='stylesheet' href='//psycho.bulash.ru/_debugbar/assets/stylesheets?v=1613988448&theme=auto'><script type='text/javascript' src='//psycho.bulash.ru/_debugbar/assets/javascript?v=1613988448'></script><script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
<script> Sfdump = window.Sfdump || (function (doc) { var refStyle = doc.createElement('style'), r...
```

Several kilobytes in answer.

So:

1. password generated successfully - as I want
2. but API answered with tons of stuff appended - why and what to do?

Comment: is there any `dd()` in your code?

Comment: Doesn't matter to put dd - junk in answer provided also in case when I just return generated password only - ```return json_encode(['password' => Str::random($length])```. I see in answer - yes, password returned, but with junk appended

Comment: That junk is what is appended by laravel debugbar, and what is generated by a `dd`. It may not be in the code you shared, check your service providers and middleware as well

Comment: Removing a debugger drops junk AFTER data returned. Maybe you know how to drop headers return BEFORE json data?

Comment: you can just return the array, no need to convert to json, see https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/responses#strings-arrays

Comment: THis error happens usually fi you don't have a json respond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was my implementation for this problem!

In blade:

```
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                headers: {'x-csrf-token': _token},
                method: 'GET',
                success: function (data) {
                    var officer = $('#officer');
                    if (data.length > 0) {
                        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                            officer.append('<option value="' + value.id + '">' + value.name + '</option>')
                        })
                    } 
                }
            })
```

My controller:

```
public function getOfficers()
{
    $officers = User::where('project', '!=', null)->get();
    return $officers;
}
```

in your case, I think you just need to return the value as it without using a response!

```
public function generatePassword(int $length = 8): string
{
    return [
        'password' => Str::random($length)
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Except ```generatePassword``` in this case should return ```array```, not ```string```

Comment: You're welcome, yes for sure you can use it as you need!

Answer (score 0):

It was not working for you because of this:

[image]

You need to return a valid JSON response.  The string typehint would convert your json to a string (so it is send without json header but with json content). For responses without json header, the debugbar will send output. See https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/issues/885

Thus, you need to change the typhint to `JsonResponse` :

```
public function generatePassword(int $length = 8): \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
{
    return [
        'password' => Str::random($length)
    ];
}
```

Note, you can avoid the `response()->json(..)` wrapper because you returning an array,

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/responses#strings-arrays):

> The framework will automatically convert the array into a JSON response

Note this is not the case for strings, so if you were to return `Hello` it would be necessary to add the wrapper:

```
public function generatePassword(int $length = 8): \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
{
    return response()->json('Hello');
}
```